# imagemagick's convert jpeg to pdf rotates even pages 180°

Tags: terminal, pdf, image-processing

When I use imagemagick's convert jpeg to pdf tool:

```
convert *.jpeg output.pdf
```

an output PDF *is* created, but what I've noticed is that the even pages get rotated by 180°.

What's even stranger is that if I open the even pages with Preview, rotate them 90° right and then rotate them 90° left, and then save it and run the `convert` command again, the page *doesn't* get rotated 180°.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong over here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the scanner I used to scan the documents I was trying to make PDFs of was saving the images with an orientation property. These were the two properties:

**Orientation: 1 (Normal)**

**Orientation: 3 (Rotated 180°)**

So, although it *looked* as though the images were upright, every second image would technically be flipped 180°, which is the property that imagemagick would use.

Removing this property from multiple images should be possible on macOS using a tool like [ExifTool.](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)